# Considerations when determining squelch

Tags: software-defined-radio, radio

I asked [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32121/coming-up-with-a-squelch-value) question recently.  From the comments I learned that squelch is not a hard and fast thing, and that many considerations might go into determining a reasonable value, depending on use, the system, etc.

In my system I've decided to average power levels on the frequency of interest.  I use a moving average, so that average might change dramatically over time.  Somewhat arbitrarily, I decided first to use $3\textrm{ dBm}$ up squelch.  So for example, if the power at the frequency is at an average of $-11\textrm{ dBm}$, I let the signal pass at $-8\textrm{ dBm}$.

I was getting way too much coming through, though (which indicates I don't understand much about the signal variance?)  So I changed it to $6$-up $\textrm{dBm}$.  But, still a lot of garbage goes through.

- $3\textrm{ dBm}$ means doubling the signal, right?  Is that not sufficient for something like, say, an analogue voice channel?  is $6\textrm{ dBm}$ up still too little, in typical application?  I really have no idea where ballpark / acceptable ranges are even.  I just need a little direction.
- I am considering combining my above technique with a static squelch level (ie. $x\textrm{ dBm}$ above average, but must be above $-x.x\textrm{ dBm}$).  Is that also a typical approach?